# Web works on android emulator but fails on Samsung galaxy S

Tags: javascript, android, galaxy

Hi:
We are developing a web app for Android. We flip the page an it fits smooth, everything works as expected.

We run tests on web browser on our test terminal (HTC Desire with Android 2.1) and with emulator running android 1.5, 1.6, 2.0, 2.1 and 2.2. Everything works as expected.

Then, the customer tests on their terminal (Samsung Galaxy S, Android 2.1) and when he flips the phone, it behaves weird, it scales poorly, and all the numbers computed from `document.documentElement.clientHeight` or `document.documentElement.clientWidth` behave weird.

Sometimes it will detect a huge screen so everything will become huge (and text is not readable), other times it will calculate a wrong width (so everything overflows) and is not usable.

Is there a way to test like in a Galaxy S? Does anybody know what changes do they have?

Answer (score 0):

Solved using their custom Galaxy Tab emulator, and found where the problem was.

Comment: How about sharing the solution for other people with the same problem?

Comment: We made lots of changes, so I don't know which specifically solved it... 
   --> Use % for sizes *$("body").css("width", "67%");*
   --> Remove the $("body").css("-webkit-text-size-adjust", "auto")
Some minor bugs on our javascript...
So I don't really know what did work... if you share your code, I'll do my best to help...